# psftp error flag using in perl

Tags: perl, putty

The script below functions just as intended. It calls the batch file which establishes a connection using PUTTY or scpecically psftp and transfers a handful of file. Once the transfer is complete i continue with the perl script to move the files to another directory.

My question is how could I capture an error from the PSFTP application? If there is an error xfering or establishing a connection i would like to generate a flag which then i could capture in perl and stop anything else from happening and send me an email. I just need guidance on generating the flag from the PSFTP application on error.

Thank you very much in advance!

My

```
use warnings;
use File::Copy;


my $TheInputDir = "//NT6/InfoSys/PatientSurvey/Invision/CFVMC/";
my $TheMoveDir = "//NT6/InfoSys/PatientSurvey/Invision/CFVMC/Completed";

system ('2166_PG_Upload_Batch.bat');


opendir (THEINPUTDIR, $TheInputDir);
@TheFiles = readdir(THEINPUTDIR);
close THEINPUTDIR;


#Get all the files that meet the naming convention
foreach $TheFile(@TheFiles) 
{
    if($TheFile =~ /2166/)
    {
        print "$TheFile\n";
        move ("$TheInputDir$TheFile","$TheMoveDir");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should read `STDERR` from your application into Perl. For that use  [Capture::Tiny](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Capture-Tiny/lib/Capture/Tiny.pm)

```
my ($stdout, $stderr, $exit) = capture {
     system('2166_PG_Upload_Batch.bat');
   };  
#check for $stderr and do your stuffs i.e sending email etc
```

For more info refer [perlfaq](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq8.html#How-can-I-capture-STDERR-from-an-external-command%3f)